# Gyöngy Theorem Proof

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can you please point me to a publicly available text that discusses the proof for the Gyöngy Theorem?

Gyöngy, I. (1986), “Mimicking the One-Dimensional Marginal Distributions
of Processes Having an Ito Differential,” Probability Theory and Related
Fields, 71, 501-516.

Any text that gives just the intuition of why this theorem is true would also be great.

Comment: See here for some intuition + light calculus : http://www.opentradingsystem.com/quantNotes/Gyongy_s_lemma_.html#Gyongy lemma section

Comment: Thanks a lot @Quantuple. The site is very useful not just for Gyöngy Lemma but for other subjects in Quant Fin too.

Comment: Glad it helped!